# PowerShell set_InnerXML on node

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm working with PowerShell to manipulate some XML and I've managed to get set_InnerXML("contents") working when creating Elements that are being added to the DOM but I've having difficulty adding a string of nodes to a node in the DOM.

Working example when creating element

```
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.Load(".\file.xml")
$newnode= $xml.CreateElement("newelament")
$newnode.set_InnerXML("<stringnode>content</stringnode>")
$root = $xml.get_DocumentElement()
$result = $root.InsertAfter($newnode, $root.get_FirstChild())
$xml.Save(".\file.xml")
```

Not working example with existing nodes

```
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.Load(".\file.xml")
$xml.node1.node2.set_InnerXML("<stringnode>content</stringnode>")
$xml.Save(".\file.xml")
```

Any sugestions on how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
PS> $xml = [xml](Get-Content ~\foo.xml)
PS> $xml | Format-Xml
<root>
  <book>
    <chapter1 />
    <chapter2 />
  </book>
</root>
```

**Update**: the use of InnerXml/InnerText properties modify the content of a node but don't seem to modify the DOM to add the new elements as XmlNodes.  For creation of new nodes that can be manipulated using the DOM, use the appropriate XmlDocument `Create` methods e.g.:

```
$book = $xml.root.book
$xml.root.book.RemoveAll()
$book -eq $xml.root.book

$intro = $xml.CreateElement("Intro")
$book.AppendChild($intro) > $null

$para = $xml.CreateElement("Para")
$intro.AppendChild($para) > $null
$xml | Format-Xml
```

Note: `Format-Xml` is a cmdlet from the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com).

Also note that I capture the `$book` xml node because after you execute `RemoveAll()` all on it, PowerShell no longer consider `book` an XmlNode but a string instead.  Seems like a case of the Xml adapter being too cute for its own good.

Comment: Thanks Keith, Your example works with book.Innerxml but does not work with book.intro.Innerxml it seems the problem is due to the book being classed as an xml node as it contains more xml but intro is being classes as a string as it contains nothing, do you have any ideas if you can make the intro node a node instead of a string?

Comment: Hi Keith, I'm still having the same problem when working on the leaf node. In you're example I'm tring to add content to the chapter1 node which is still being treated as a string.

Comment: Make sure you're not using InnerText/InnerXml.  Stick with just the CreateElement/AppendChild methods.  As noted above, you have to be careful even then with certain methods like RemoveAll().